# Seeking examples of non-rectifiable curves, preferably with explicit expressions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, curves

I've been considering for a while the problem of non rectifiable curves.
For example, my book showed me a curve defined such as
If $$ f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb R$$ $$f(t)= t\sin\left(\frac {\pi} {2t}\right), f(0)=0$$ and
$$ \gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2, \gamma(t)=(t, f(t)) $$ and led me to prove it is has an infinite length, after a long argument (with polygonal chains and inequalities).

Then I started looking for other examples, and came across the famous Koch's and Peano's curves, but didn't find many of them.

I'm wondering:

> Do you know other curves which are not rectifiable, preferably with an explicit expression, when it exists (such as the one I wrote beforehand)? Is there a "list" of the most important ones?

Comment: Certainly the function that is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals is an example on any interval of positive length. Also any unbounded function on $[0,1]$ is an example.

Comment: The curve associated with Weierstrass's [nowhere differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is non-rectifable.
If function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ describes a rectifiable curve, then $f$ has [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) and differentiable almost everywhere....

Answer (score 1):

The argument showing that your $\gamma$ has infinite length need not be long. For any $N\in \mathbb N,$ the length will be at least

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}|\gamma(1/2n)-\gamma(1/(2n-1))| \ge\sum_{n=1}^{N}|f(1/2n)-f(1/(2n-1))|$$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|1/(2n)\cdot\sin(n\pi) - 1/(2n-1)\cdot \sin((2n-1)\pi/2) | =  \sum_{n=1}^{N}=1/(2n-1).$$

The last sum $\to \infty$ as $N\to \infty.$ Thus the length of $\gamma$ is  $\infty.$

Comment: Great. I was also interested in getting to know other examples of this sort of curves, especially notable or important ones. I mean, I didn't know the functions in the comments before, and I was looking for uncommon and maybe strange functions (to get a better idea of what a function/curve can be, and not to be always dealing with polynomials or "smooth" stuff).